# Pageable in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pageable

I want to return "ownDemand" as Page of demand. How can I do that

```
@Override
public Page<Demand> getDemandbyId(Long id, Pageable pageable) {
   Iterable<Demand> alldemand = demandRepository.findAll(); 
   List<Demand> ownDemand = new ArrayList<Demand>();
   for (Demand demand : alldemand) {
       if(demand.getStore().getId()==id) {
           ownDemand.add(demand);
       }
  }
    return null;
 }
 }
```

*Demand Repository*

```
@RestResource
public interface DemandRepository extends JpaRepository<Demand,Long> {
}
```

Comment: Please add your `DemandRepository` and entity class like `Demand`. And you can call findAll with pageable method

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks,  But I dont want return findAll I want return demands of an store that have the id 
whan I instanciate Page<Demand> = new Page() and other method(sort number page ....) that I dont know how

Comment: Don't, please don't. This will lead to issues when you have a lot of `Demand` instances (memory, performance). Just write a proper query(method) for it. Something like `Page<Demand> findAllByStoreId(Long storeId, Pageable page)`; which will return exactly what you need AND uses the power of the database instead of pulling everythingi n memory and do paging and filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a method to your DemandRepository like so

```
Page<Demand> findAllByStore(Store store, Pageable page)
```

This assumes that StoreEntity is related to Demand, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

demandRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 2))

By signature it returns Page. Change PageRequest according to your fit.

Comment: But I dont want return findAll I want return demands of an store that have the id whan I instanciate Page<Demand> = new Page() and other method(sort number page ....) that I dont know how

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749559/conversion-of-list-to-page-in-spring 
Looks like your issue is duplicate of this.