# Creating a Spring Data Page from a simple collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a Spring utility that allows to create a [`Page`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) instance starting from a Java Collection?

Something like:

```
Page<MyObject> myObjPage = PagingUtils.createPageFromCollection(listOfMyObjects, pageable);
```

Or should I manually implement paging and sorting logic manually?

Comment: A `Page` is just a holder for data it doesn't do paging and sorting. That is left to the repository to implement. Why do you want to turn a collection into a page in the first place?

Comment: @M.Deinum in my project the collection acts as a "table" so, I need to retrieve a page of what is contained in this collection.

Comment: Then you need to write a repository that handles your collection as a table and does sorting/paging on that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be answered with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749559/conversion-of-list-to-page-in-spring).

Answer seems u need to implement manually.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 2 scenarios-

1. I want data from spring as paging and sorting  then 
   i) Create a sort object of (org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)

```
Sort sort = sortType.equals("ASC") ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
                Sort.by(sortField).descending();
```

ii) Pass this sort type to a pageable object

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageId, pageSize, sort);
```

iii) Pass this pageable object to JPArepository method

```
yourRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

This will return data with pagination and sorting.

**Case 2 - Your scenario - From a collection object I want data with pagination**

then you have to take the help from PageImpl class.
which offer 2 Constructor to do this

```
PageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total)
```

where

1. content – the content of this page(Your collection object).
2. pageable – the paging information
3. total – the total amount of items available.

There is also another constructor

```
PageImpl(List<T> content)
```

**Note - This will result in the created Page being identical to the entire List.**

Answer (score 0):

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo-1, pageSize);

Page page = questionRepository.findAll(pageable);

List question = page.getContent();